# what pack/do i use to create workspace in ros electric?

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

what pack/do i use to create workspace in ros electric ?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/194078/what-pack/do-i-use-to-create-workspace-in-ros-electric-?/) by [nicoly](https://answers.ros.org/users/20372/nicoly/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2014-10-02

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

ROS Electric is no longer supported. I **STRONGLY** recommend that you upgrade to a newer version of ROS.

ROS electric only uses the old rosbuild build system. You can create rosbuild packages with `roscreate-pkg`.

---

Originally posted by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) with karma: 47576 on 2014-10-02

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 2

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [nicoly](https://answers.ros.org/users/20372/nicoly/) on 2014-10-07**:
The problem is that i can't create rosbuild packages. I tried **roscreate-pkg learning_nxt rospy nxt_ros** but don't work. Do you know why ?